# parse json object response from php web service

Tags: android, json

i have gone through a number of tutorials to get an idea as to how can we parse JSON object. the structure of ma JSON object response from web service is like this

```
{"posts":[

{"gpoint":{"latitude":"18.966364","longitude":"72.811317"}},

{"gpoint":{"latitude":"19.07023","longitude":"72.82917"}},

{"gpoint":{"latitude":"19.094889","longitude":"72.840157"}},

{"gpoint":{"latitude":"19.056601","longitude":"72.901955"}}]

}
```

and this is my code:

```
       HttpResponse response= client.execute(post);

       content = response.getEntity().getContent();

       String result = stringConversion(content);   


       jObject = new JSONObject(result);

       JSONArray gpoint = jObject.getJSONArray("posts");

       for (int i = 0; i<gpoint.length();i++)
       {

            double geoLat=gpoint.getJSONObject(i).optDouble("latitude");
            double geoLong=gpoint.getJSONObject(i).optDouble("longitude");

       //   double geoLat = gPointObject.getDouble("latitude");
       //   double geoLong = gPointObject.getDouble("longitude");      
            Log.i(Tag," "+ geoLat);
            Log.i(Tag," "+ geoLong);
       }

}   


catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

I am not able to parse this response, whenever I am parsing it, it does not give any parse exception but the value for latitude and longitude is NaN

Kindly tell me, where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject gp;
for (int i = 0; i<gpoint.length();i++)
        {
gp = gpoint.getJSONObject(i);
double geoLat = gp.getJSONObject("gpoint").optDouble("latitude");
double geoLong = gp.getJSONObject("gpoint").optDouble("latitude");

        //  double geoLat = gPointObject.getDouble("latitude");
        //  double geoLong = gPointObject.getDouble("longitude");      
            Log.i(Tag," "+ geoLat);
            Log.i(Tag," "+ geoLong);
       }
```

You're missing one nesting layer.

Comment: Glad to help. It happens all the time: you are sitting so close to the problem you don't notice your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use GSON. If you prepare adequate DTO structure, you can map your JSON in one function call. I'm using it in my app.